# jQuery Autocomplete Substring Matching

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm attempting to do jQuery autocomplete such that I can search for multiple words.

For example, if I have `smart`, `very smart`, and `super smart` in a list I'd like to be able to start typing `smar` and have all three options show up.

This code will work in the sense that if I start typing from the very beginning like `over` it will suggest `over smart` which is correct. But it wouldn't suggest it if I type just `smart` which is the desired output.

Any idea how I can adjust the code so that I could search and suggest say a substring within the list?

http://jsfiddle.net/UKgD6/390/

```
var acList = ['smart',
'over smart',
'smart land',
'under smart',
'very smart'
];

$('#ac').autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    var matches = $.map( acList, function(acItem) {
      if ( acItem.toUpperCase().indexOf(request.term.toUpperCase()) === 0 ) {
        return acItem;
      }
    });
    response(matches);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue can be fixed by changing the `indexOf()` check. Change `=== 0` to `!== -1`. This will return anything that matches, no matter what the index of the search string is within the actual string.

http://jsfiddle.net/UKgD6/391/